# Set image resource to remoteView using volley

Tags: android, android-volley, android-remoteview

I play a music stream from service in android so when the music start playing , a notification appears above and show play/pause button , the title of the music and and a thumbnail to the music cover photo . I initiate the notification inside the service code like the following :

```
int icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
    long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
    notification = new Notification(icon, "", when);

    mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationContentView = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.custom_notification);
    notificationContentView.setImageViewResource(R.id.thumbnailNotification, R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    notificationContentView.setTextViewText(R.id.albumtitleNotification, sntSongAlbum);
    notificationContentView.setTextViewText(R.id.songnameNotification, sntSongTitle);
    notification.contentView = notificationContentView;

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, OpenSongActivity.class);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
    notification.contentIntent = contentIntent;

    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR;
```

where **custom_notification.xml** looks like :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/layout"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/thumbnailNotification"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />

<TextView android:id="@+id/albumtitleNotification"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/thumbnailNotification"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    style="Custom Notification Title" />
<TextView android:id="@+id/songnameNotification"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/thumbnailNotification"
    android:layout_below="@id/albumtitleNotification"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    style="Custom Notification Text" />




<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:id="@+id/closeButton"
    android:background="@android:drawable/presence_offline"
    android:clickable="false" />


<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/playNotification"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@android:drawable/ic_media_pause" />
```

and this work perfectly and set the ic_launcher icon which included in resources folder in the ImageView , But what i want to achieve is to set this image to an image from url and since i use volley library to download and set images i replaced the ImageView with the id=thumbnailNotification inside **thumbnailNotification.xml** to the following :

```
   <com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
    android:id="@+id/thumbnailNotification"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    aandroid:layout_marginRight="10dp />
```

but now how to set this from the service ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up using BitmapFactory to set the image since i didn't find any way to use volley with remoteViews  :

```
  public class NotificationImageAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {

    @Override protected Bitmap doInBackground(Void... params) {
        Bitmap bm = null;
        try {
            URL aURL = new URL(params[0]);
            URLConnection conn = aURL.openConnection();
            conn.connect();
            InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
            bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bis);
            bis.close();
            is.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error getting bitmap", e);
        }
        return bm;
    }

    @Override protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {

         notificationContentView.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.thumbnailNotification , result);
    }
}
```

...

```
new NotificationImageAsyncTask().execute("Image URL");
```

Comment: My goal was to download image in a background service and show image in a notification to user, so i ended up scrapping the whole AsyncTask fiesta, since services are not in main thread.